# Unable to run git on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: git, macos, terminal, apple-m1, xcode-command-line-tools

Unable to run git on new MacBook running Big Sur

When I try to run git, I receive the following error:

> xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): could not use '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' because it is not a compatible arch).

I followed the method of forcing which architecture loads, suggested [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652377), but still, I’m experiencing the error.

Now, after running that suggestion I am seeing the following error:

> manpath: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture).

I also installed homebrew prior to that error message, although I don’t see how that would be related.

I really lack experience interacting with Xcode. I feel like on my previous Mac I was just able to get up and running, without any of this hassle, but it’s been awhile so perhaps I'm forgetting.

How can I identify if Xcode and Command Line Tools are properly installed? If they are not, what is the recommended way to add them?

I tried installing homebrew to see if I could use it as a work-around, and tried using it to install git, but received the following error:

> 'brew install git
> Updating Homebrew...
> Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
> Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the "Alternative Installs" from: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

I am on a MacBook Pro with the new M1 chip- could that be related?

Comment: Try installing command line tools again? `xcode-select --install`?

Comment: thanks, I went ahead and tried this and received the following message: 'xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates' -so it appears xcode is installed but maybe not behaving? do you happen to know the command for software update?

Comment: however, if I run softwareupdate --list no available updates are returned :-/

Comment: Try removing Xcode and reinstalling it from the App Store?

Answer (score 20):

ok will boy do I feel stupid- the problem was I did not have xcode installed. I became confused because the error messages seemed to indicated xcode was already present and there was an xcode directory on my machine- perhaps that directory comes preinstalled in preparation for xcode?

At any rate, I solved my issue by downloading and installing xcode from the app store. Maybe this will help somebody else out

Comment: The error message is very misleading: "error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"

Answer (score 18):

Try with the following command:

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

It will remove the command line tool and then immediately install the software automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Wow. Now I also feel really stupid. I also didn't have xcode installed, but I definitely thought I did because I had it installed on my old machine. Apparently when transferring everything to the new machine, xcode didn't come along for the ride.

Answer (score 4):

1. First, install or update the xcode in App Store
2. Then, run `sudo xcodebuild -license` in terminal
3. And type `agree` at the end of Xcode license agreements

Now can use the `git`

Comment: This worked for me after an update to XCode 13 from 12.x.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Mac M1 chip use this command to change to the old xcode can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also get git from https://brew.sh/, which I believe is fairly common!

With the edit, I don't have an Apple Silicon chip to test with, but the [brew docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) say it should be installed to `/opt/homebrew` (literally untar in that path)

If this is a fresh install and not upgrading an existing one, however, you may not be able to get away from having Xcode as you'll almost-certainly require *some* compiler or component for a few packages. Existing installs should move the path or delete and rebuild (collect all your top-level packages with `brew leaves && brew list -1 --cask`)

```sh
brew install git
```

You may also need/want to provide a resolution for this warning if it appears

> ```
> hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
> hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
> hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
> hint:
> hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
> hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
> hint:   git config pull.ff only>    # fast-forward only
> hint:
> hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
> hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
> hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
> hint: invocation.
> ```

`pull.ff only` is a reasonable choice, as it'll it will only do a fast-forward if you have a local conflict when attempting to pull (modified local and remote)

```sh
git config --global pull.ff only
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i was having this same issue with my MAC as well. I was able to resolve it by running the code below. Works like magic.

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue. Updating my mac to Big Sur 11.3 fixed it.